# Why is the Cache-Control always "no-cache" and "X-Drupal-Dynamic-Cache" UNCACHEABLE on this site?

Tags: 9, caching, performance

I have a production website for quite a long time now.
By digging, we found that the *Cache-Control* was always to "*no-cache*" and "*X-Drupal-Dynamic-Cache*" is *UNCACHEABLE*

[image]

My settings.prod.php look like this

```
# ================================================================
# Performance settings
# ================================================================
$config['system.logging']['error_level'] = ERROR_REPORTING_HIDE;
$config['system.performance']['cache']['page']['max_age'] = 86400;
$config['system.performance']['css']['preprocess'] = TRUE;
$config['system.performance']['css']['gzip'] = TRUE;
$config['system.performance']['js']['preprocess'] = TRUE;
$config['system.performance']['js']['gzip'] = TRUE;
```

And this is my services.prod.yml

```
parameters:
  http.response.debug_cacheability_headers: false
  twig.config:
    debug: false
    auto_reload: false
    cache: true
```

I have both `dynamic_page_cache` and `page_cache` enable on the website, because we have both anonymous and logged users.

Furthermore, the config settings is not display in the backend `System > Development > Performance`, is the cache really activated like this ?

Comment: Yes, config overrides don’t show up on the admin form unless the module developers have written some code to make that happen (some do but most don’t). Rather than global settings, it feels likely that something in the page build is declaring itself as uncacheable, and that’s bubbling up to the top level. You might have something varying on date, for example, sometimes people hook up the footer copyright year to a dynamic var without realising the cache implications

Comment: If you're on D9.5 or above you could try turning this caching debug on and it might help trace what is causing the uncachable https://www.drupal.org/node/3162480 Common things like captchas and the facets module can cause the whole page to be uncachable

Comment: I agree with the commenters above. This isn't about site settings but rather something a module is doing.

Comment: There are many factors that could make a page not cacheable, including a session containing data.

Answer (score 1):

I've uninstall `page_cache` and keept `dynamic_page_cache` to have a `max-age=3600` enabled.

I've also remove a remaining `killswitch` which causes issue with custom block.

As it is a `context user website` (drupal commerce), when the user is adding a product, **x-dynamic-cache** became **uncacheable**